# XCode 12 error with IMP instance: Too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, imp

I just got some work for the old project. There is compile-time error with IMP instance:

[image]

While searching for the cause and solution I came across the links:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666701

But those didn't helped me understand the solution. What should be done to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1):

The solution given at https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666988 worked for me. There is some warning, but at least build is successful.

```
id (*grannyImp)(Class, SEL) = (id(*)(Class,SEL))class_getMethodImplementation(granny, _cmd);
//IMP grannyImp = class_getMethodImplementation(granny, _cmd);
grannyImp(self, _cmd);
```